# Rapidjson: How to Get() an enumerator

Tags: c++, json, enums, rapidjson

I am trying to implement a Exploding Kittens card game, where the type of the card is an enumerator class.

```
enum class card_type
{
    Kitten,
    Bomb,
    ...
}
```

and use it as a private variable `card_type* value`. Afterwards, as I pass the events as JSON queries, I would like to get the value from JSON using RapidJSON.

```
static serializable_value<T>* from_json(const rapidjson::Value& json) 
{
    if (json.HasMember("value")) {
        T val = json["value"].Get<T>();
        return new serializable_value<T>(val);
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

and call it as

```
serializable_value<card_type>::from_json(json["value"].GetObject())
```

where serializable_value is just a helper class for handling JSON.

This code works perfectly fine, if I don't use enum class, but rather use `int* value` and `serializable_value<int>::from_json(json["value"].GetObject())`

How to handle a enum class which should be nothing more, but an unsigned int?

Also here a full stack trace:

```
error: no member named 'Get' in 'rapidjson::internal::TypeHelper<rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<>>, card_type>'
    T Get() const { return internal::TypeHelper<ValueType, T>::Get(*this); }
                                                               ^
/src/common/game_state/cards/../../serialization/serializable_value.h:52:35: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<>>::Get<card_type>' requested here
            T val = json["value"].Get<T>();
                                  ^
/src/common/game_state/cards/card.cpp:35:80: note: in instantiation of member function 'serializable_value<card_type>::from_json' requested here
        return new card(json["id"].GetString(), serializable_value<card_type>::from_json(json["value"].GetObject()));
```

Comment: Are you allowed to make an integral type (such as `size_t`) a base type of `card_type`?

Comment: yes, I could also just use strings for serialization.

Comment: Writing a specialization of `from_json` (and the corresponding `to_json`) is also an option, yes.

Comment: How exactly is your comment helping me in any way? It is obvious, that I am not advancing on the task due to limited skills. I neither know, whether you suggest an actual implementation approach or just write something rather general or even not possible at all.

Comment: Sorry, from your comment I understood you had already considered that as an option and were asking about a different way. So no, it is not obvious that you are limited by skills. Can you edit your question with the full declaration of `from_json`, `to_json`, the `serializable_value` template class , and a small [mre] so I (or someone else) can produce an answer that works?